# Force App to be started in a new task in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Let says there are App A and App B, I want App A to launch an activity which belongs to App B, the default behaviour of that is the activity will be added in the back stack of App A.

I'm aware of by adding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag in the intent that starts App B's activity (with possibly setting the taskAffinity of the activity in App B) will make the activity be created in the back stack of App B.

However, what I want to know is, is there a way to force App A to create the activity in a new task? Therefore whenever App A starts a new intent which opens an activity in App B, the activity get created in a new task even if the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag is not set.

My thought is to start an intent with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag when that App B activity is created, so that a new task will be created with this activity on top, but that sounds hacky so I'm finding a more direct approach.

Comment: use broadcast receiver for this

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti can you explain in more details?

Comment: You should not do this. Why would you want to break user expectations and the Recents screen from working correctly?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it's the user's requirement, I need to launch the activity in a new task so that App A and App B can be removed individually.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of the requirement that App A has specifically designed their app to accomplish: treating App B as a part of their own task (and on devices that support multiple windows such as Chromebooks or tablets in multi-window mode, in their same window). If 'a user' thinks that App A is doing it wrong, then they should contact App A, shouldn't they?

Comment: App A is out of the user/my control, we need to assume App A may not use the NEW_TASK flag when starting an intent, and the activity in App B (our app) still need to be started in a new task.